# How can I delete the row having specific contiditon?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to delete the row that is column 'revenue' = 0 or 'Budget' = 0 from the movie table
so I tried this code.

```
movies[(movies['revenue'] == 0) or (movies['Budget'] == 0)]
```

Then, I got a value error

So I tried this code as well

```
columns = ['budget', 'revenue']
df = movies.replace(0, pd.np.nan).dropna(axis=0, how='any', subset = columns).fillna(0).astype(int)
```

also I got an Future warning " The pandas.np module is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Import numpy directly instead.
plus, value error that traceback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the `or` operator there, you have to use the logical or `|` sign:

```
movies = movies[(movies['revenue'] == 0) & (movies['Budget'] == 0)]
```

**Edit:**

If you want to remove the rows with `0`, try using the `~` sign:

```
movies = movies[~(movies['revenue'] == 0) & ~(movies['Budget'] == 0)]
```

**I use `&` since OP said in the comments that he needs `&`**

Comment: but I still have the row that revenue = 0

Comment: @박인아 I edited my answer , please check it out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226344/discussion-between--and-u11-forward).

Answer (score 4):

Try this, and use `|` bitwise operator (means `or`):

```
new = movies[(movies['revenue'] != 0) | (movies['budget'] != 0)]
```

The code will create a new `df` with the rows that are not 0 in column or not 0 in budget.

Note that `!=` means not equal. For extra information on operators, I find this link clear: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_operators.asp

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the below line -

```
drop_idx = movies[(movies['revenue'] == 0) or (movies['Budget'] == 0)].index
```

to

```
drop_idx = movies[(movies['revenue'] == 0) | (movies['Budget'] == 0)].index
```

Once you have the drop indexes you can use `drop` to delete the indexes

```
movies = movies.drop(index=drop_idx)
```

Comment: I tried but I got a KeyError: "['id' 'imdb_id' 'popularity' 'budget' 'revenue' 'original_title' 'cast'\n 'homepage' 'director' 'tagline' 'keywords' 'overview' 'runtime' 'genres'\n 'production_companies' 'release_date' 'vote_count' 'vote_average'\n 'release_year' 'budget_adj' 'revenue_adj' 'movies_count'] not found in axis"

Comment: Updated the answer to rectify this error